# How can I sort XML entries with LibXML and Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, sorting, libxml2

I'm parsing an XML file with [LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML) and need to sort the entries by date. Each entry has two date fields, one for when the entry was published and one for when it was updated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<entry>
  <published>2009-04-10T18:51:04.696+02:00</published>
  <updated>2009-05-30T14:48:27.853+03:00</updated>
  <title>The title</title>
  <content>The content goes here</content>
</entry>
...
```

The XML file is already ordered by date updated, with the most recent first. I can easily reverse that to put the older entries first:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($file);
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc->documentElement());

foreach my $entry (reverse($xc->findnodes('//entry'))) {
  ...
}
```

However, I need to reverse sort the file by date published, not by date updated. How can I do that? The timestamp looks a little wonky too. Would I need to normalize that first?

Thanks!

Update:
After fiddling around with XPath namespaces and failing, I made a function that parsed the XML and stored the values I needed in a hash. I then used a bare `sort` to sort the hash, which works just fine now.

Comment: Glad to see you went the XML::LibXML route.  It is a little hard to get used to XML's strictness, but it will save you a lot of time in the long run.  (I have had to work with vendors that took shortcuts in implementing XML, meaning I couldn't actually give them XML, I had to give them some sort of tag soup.  Very irritating.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be changing your `reverse` to a `sort` statement (untested):

```
sub parse_date {
    # Transforms date from 2009-04-10T18:51:04.696+02:00 to 20090410
    my $date= shift;
    $date= join "", $date =~ m!\A(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*!;
    return $date;
}

sub by_published_date {
    my $a_published= parse_date( $a->getChildrenByTagName('published') );
    my $b_published= parse_date( $b->getChildrenByTagName('published') );

    # putting $b_published in front will ensure the descending order.
    return $b_published <=> $a_published;
}

foreach my $entry ( sort by_published_date $xc->findnodes('//entry') ) {
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Ah, I see now, I think... $a and $b are two individual entries, right? How could I programatically go through all of the entries, though? Some files have hundreds of entries...

Comment: $a and $b are filled in by the sort function. All your function needs to do, for any two items in your list, is return -1 if $a should sort before $b, 1 if $b should sort before $a, and 0 otherwise. sort will handle the rest.

Comment: Just to clarify (because you asked "how you programatically go through all the entries"): sort will call your function many times, each time with two values from your list (but in no specific order).

Comment: Alright... this is almost working, except that the xPath is a little more complex than just 'published'--it's './post:published'. I have the namespace declared earlier as $xc->registerNs(post => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'); but once the object is recast as $a and $b it loses the namespace. Any way to maintain the namespace inside the sub?

Comment: Just to be a bit more specific: `$a` and `$b` are global variables used by `sort` function. For more information about them, you can read  `perldoc -f sort` on the command line, or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html.

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you talking about. In the example I wrote, $a and $b are simply references to some element returned by $xc->findnodes().

Comment: The problem is with xPath. In your example, $a and $b get set to getChildrenByTagName('published'). In my XML file, though, the node has a name space: <post:published>...</pu...>. If I leave the simple 'published' name as the attribute for $a and $b the script fails because $a and $b both end up null. If I put the full xPath as the attribute the script fails because the namespace is unknown. So I need to somehow reference the namespace somewhere in the sort function... I just can't figure out where...

Comment: Perhaps you should use getChildrenByTagNameNS() instead. Did you check XML::LibXML::Element documentation about those methods?

Comment: Yeah, I've been messing with the different NS fucntions in LibXML::Element but nothing's working. I'm going to try a different approach...

Comment: I don't have much experience with XML::LibXML, I prefer to use XML::Twig. Perhaps you could give it a try.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are omitting the http:// from the namespace.  Make sure you use the same namespace URI that the document declares "post" to be.  (And remember, you can't use the short names as namespaces -- those are shortcuts for the markup, not shortcuts for parsing.  Always use the URI.)

Answer (score 2):

A bare sort may put times from different timezones out of order:

```
 print for sort "2009-06-15T08:00:00+07:00", "2009-06-15T04:00:00+00:00";
```

Here, the second time is 3 hours after the first, but sorts first.

I'm not sure what you mean by "wonky". Your example just shows timestamps in [rfc3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) format.

Comment: Ah. I thought those timestamps were some proprietary thing and not an actual format. Thanks!